# How to use a certain question inserted in Text widget and check if the user answered yes or no?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a chat program in Tkinter using an Entry widget for user input and a Text widget for output. The program starts with a question inserted in the Text widget and if the user answers "yes"(by pressing ReturnKey) another question is inserted using Text.insert() method. How can a check to which question inserted did the user answered "yes" so it keeps the conversation flowing?

```
'''' #making the widgets''''
input_field = Entry(root)
chat = Text(root)
'''''
def intro():
  chat.insert(INSERT, question1)
chat.after(1000, intro)

def Enter_pressed(event):
  input_get = input_field
  chat.insert(INSERT, '%s\n' % input_get, "right")
  input_field.focus()
  question2 =str(....)
  question3 =str(...)
  question4 =str(...)
  if input_get == "yes":
      if question1:
         chat.insert(INSERT, question2)
      elif question2:
         chat.insert(INSERT, question3)
  elif input_get == "no":
     chat.insert(INSERT, question4)
 input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the cleanest way to do it, but you can use a generator combined with a modified `enter_pressed` func:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
questions = ["Q1","Q2","Q3"] #first store the questions in a list
answers = {} #store question and answer pair

def enter_pressed(event):
    if input_field.get().lower() == "yes":
        print ("YES")
        answers[i] = "yes" #append to answer dict
    elif input_field.get().lower() == "no":
        print ("NO")
        answers[i] = "no" #append to answer dict
    else:
        print ("Wrong answer!")
        input_field.delete(0, tk.END)
        return
    input_field.delete(0, tk.END)
    try:
        next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        print ("No more questions!")
        print (answers)

def generate_questions():
    global i
    for i in questions:
        chat.insert(tk.END,i+"\n")
        yield i

input_field = tk.Entry(root)
input_field.pack()
input_field.bind("<Return>",enter_pressed)
generator = generate_questions()
chat = tk.Text(root)
chat.pack()
next(generator)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

with an OO approach it's all simplest. See below, if you respond yes the script load another question, anyway it write all your answers...and a response...;)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


class Main(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.answer = tk.StringVar()

        self.questions = ("There is anybody ot there?",
                          "Did you like spaghetti?",
                          "Is the weather nice in Italy in the winter?",
                          "Did you like this example?",)

        self.init_ui()


    def init_ui(self):


        f = ttk.Frame()

        ttk.Label(f, text = "Answer").pack()

        self.txAnswer = ttk.Entry(f, textvariable=self.answer)
        self.txAnswer.pack(fill=tk.X, expand=1)
        self.txAnswer.bind("<Return>",self.get_answer)

        self.txQuestion = ScrolledText(f)
        self.txQuestion.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

        f.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)


    def on_set_question(self,):
        self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, '\nQ:')
        self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, self.questions[0])
        self.which = 0
        self.clear_answer()

    def get_answer(self, evt=None):

        if self.answer.get() in ("Yes","yes","YES","42"):

            if self.which ==len(self.questions)-1:
                self.which = 0
            else:
                self.which +=1

            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, '\nA:')
            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, self.answer.get())                
            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, '\nQ:')                
            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, self.questions[self.which])            

        else:
            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, '\nA:')
            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, self.answer.get())
            self.txQuestion.insert(tk.END, "\nThis is not the right answer...")

        self.clear_answer()            

    def clear_answer(self):

        self.answer.set('')
        self.txAnswer.focus()

    def on_close(self):
        self.parent.on_exit()

class App(tk.Tk):
    """Start here"""

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)

        self.set_title()
        self.set_style()

        Main(self,).on_set_question()

    def set_style(self):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        #('winnative', 'clam', 'alt', 'default', 'classic', 'vista', 'xpnative')
        self.style.theme_use("clam")

    def set_title(self):
        s = "{0}".format('Simple App')
        self.title(s)

    def on_exit(self):
        """Close all"""
        if messagebox.askokcancel("Simple App", "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
            self.destroy()               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking the nested if/else statements completely wrong. Your version worked  for what I was intending to do. I have a curiosity: is it posible to allign the user's answer to the right of the widget? In the Text widget it was posible using "justif=right".

Comment: I' think yes, see '\n' in every insert(tk.END, '\n :') it force the text go to a new line....